# How to display the data from the list as tabular form

Tags: haskell

--[(Teacher,subject,class,extrasub)]

```
test =[("Sam","Maths","Std5","PE"),
       ("Sam","Maths","Std7","PE"),
       ("Sam","geography","Std6","PE"),
       ("Jake","English","Std9","Red Cross"),
       ("Jake","English","Std9","Guards")]
```

It should look like this

```
    Teacher         Subject     Class   ExtraClass
    Sam             Maths       Std5    PE
                                Std7
                    Geography   Std6
    Jake            English     Std9    Red Cross
                                        Guards
```

i want the output to be like this

```
[
("Jake","English","Std9","Red Cross"),
("","","","Guards"),
("Sam","Maths","Std7","PE"),
("","","Std5",""),
("","geography","Std6","PE")]



test2 :: [([Char], [Char], [Char], [Char])]
test2 = test3 $ concat $ groupBy (\(x,_,_,_) (y,_,_,_) -> x==y) (sort test1)

test3 [] = []
test3 [x] = []

test3 ((a1,b1,c1,d1):(a2,b2,c2,d2):xs) =
                                        if(a1==a2 && b1== b2&& d1==d2)
                                            then [("","",c1,d1)]
                                         else if (a1==a2)
                                            then [("","",c1,d1)]
                                         else [("",b1,c1,d1)]
```

i was thinking of this approach using foldl' but couldnt get it. any suggestion on how to go about on this

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually quite hard. You will have to solve two problems:

1. How to transform the input so that duplicate fields in consecutive rows are replaced with blank
   space.
2. How to print the result in nice columns.

Let us discuss these problems one by one.

1. Transform the input.

   What do we have to do? If there are duplicate values in consecutive cells along any given
   column, we would like to replace all of them, except the first, with blank space. So, we may do
   like this:

   1. Analyze each column as a list.
   2. If there are duplicate values, keep only the first one and replace all others with blank
      space.
   3. The tricky moment is that, if the first column's value changes, we would like to stop
      blanking cells and print at least one row in full. To ensure this, we may break the table in
      sections so that for each possible value of the first column, there is one section.

   How do we accomplish this? My take:

   ```
   -- First, I'd like to define some type synonyms to make type signatures more
   -- intuitive.

   type Row = [String]

   type Table = [Row]

   -- It would be easier to deal with a row represented as a list, rather than a
   -- tuple.

   tupleToList :: (String, String, String, String) -> Row
   tupleToList (a, b, c, d) = [a, b, c, d]

   -- With some handy library functions, we can convert our input to Rows and
   -- section it by teacher's name in one pass:

   test' :: [Table]
   test' = groupBy equalFirstColumn . map tupleToList $ test
     where
       equalFirstColumn = ((==) `on` head)

   -- Now, we have to blank the repeating values. If the columns were lists, we
   -- would do it like this:

   blankRepetitions :: [String] -> [String]
   blankRepetitions (x:xs) = x: replicate (length bef) "" ++ blankRepetitions aft
       where (bef, aft) = span (== x) xs
   blankRepetitions [ ] = [ ]

   -- Luckily, there is a library function that can turn columns to rows and vice
   -- versa. Let's use it.

   test'' :: [Table]
   test'' = map (transpose . map blankRepetitions . transpose) test'

   -- Now we can turn our groups back into a single table. Why not add a row with
   -- column captions as well.

   test3 :: Table
   test3 = ["Teacher", "Subject", "Class", "ExtraClass"] : concat test''
   ```

   Take some time to study this and see if it works as expected. I have a lingering suspicion that
   the way I deal with blanking has some flaws to it...
2. Print the result.

   By far the simplest way to obtain a nice looking table is simply to pad every cell with spaces
   so that every cell has the same width:

   ```
   pad :: Int -> String -> String
   pad w s = " " ++ s ++ (replicate (w - length s) ' ')
   ```

   But what width to choose? The width of the longest cell seems like a nice choice. So, we can go
   like that:

   ```
   columnize :: Table -> String
   columnize xss = unlines . map concat . (map.map) (pad maxwidth) $ xss
       where maxwidth = maximum . map length . concat $ xss
   ```

   Notice how `map.map` processes a list of lists in the same way as a single `map` would process
   a plain one.

---

That's it! See how it's easy to deal with a complicated problem once you turn it into a few
smaller ones.

Comment: @AlexiaDesouza If you wish to contact me personally, there's an email in the profile. Otherwise, post a question and someone will answer.